# Getting error PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR after DB switches to Idle state

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

During off hours, the DB goes in the Idle state. So I am reconnecting the data using the following snippet,

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var settings = require('./config.js');

var connection;

function handleDisconnect() {

connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: settings.dbhost,
    user: settings.user,
    password: settings.password,
    database: settings.database
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error when connecting to db:', err, settings.database);
        setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Database is connected ...", settings.database);
    }
});

connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('db error', err, settings.database);
    if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {

        connection
        handleDisconnect();
    } else {
        throw err;
    }
});
}

handleDisconnect();

module.exports = connection;
```

When executing DB query, I am getting the following error:

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "Error": {
        "code": "PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR",
        "fatal": false
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, me too facing the same issue

Comment: For a meanwhile I switched to sql.ConnectionPool()

Comment: Yes, it's the possible solution but we have to find alternative ways too.

Answer (score 0):

One possible, but imperfect solution is to use `sql.ConnectionPool()`